# JNI: vcvars32.bat gives me "Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: java, c, visual-studio, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNI to integrate a .C code with my Java project.

While trying to generate the .dll file using vcvars32.bat in visual studio 2017 it gives me an error message tells:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\include\jni.h(39): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory"

I removed the including of stdio.h library in my C code but it didn't help.

My command is:

"cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\include\win32" -LD "Factorial.c" -Fe"Factorial.dll""

Comment: Are you sure that you jvm is 32bit ? In 2018 it sounds strange, i.e. in most cases you need vcvars64.bat

Comment: I tried vcvars64.bat, vcvarsall.bat and even VsDevCmd.bat too but unfortunately it didn't help too

Comment: Ok, let's make some simple nmake file and check:

Comment: make a file like `link: compile ln  /DLL /LTCG /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib"  OUT:factorial.dll msvcrt.lib kernel32.lib  jvm.lib Factorial.obj    compile: cl /c /nologo /GL /Zl   Factorial.c /FoFactorial.obj` and Use nmake to build it. The Nmake manuals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/nmake-reference http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~dskim/downloadable/reference_Nmake.pdf

Comment: *I removed the including of stdio.h library in my C code but it didn't help.*  You're not going to be able to compile 32- or 64-bit without the standard C headers. Something is likely wrong with your Visual Studio install.  What's the full path to the `vcvars32.bat` file that you used to set up your environment?  Can you try another one?  Can you compile a simple "Hello World!" C program in the Visual Studio GUI that has `#include <stdio.h>` in it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle the full path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build" , there are vcvars, vcvars32, vcvars64, vcvarsall, vcvarsamd64_arm, vcvarsamd64_x86, vcvarsx86_amd64 and vcvarsx86_arm and none of them works, yea I can create WindowsDesktopWizard and run C project

Comment: IIRC, with VS2107 you need to use a batch called `(something)devenv.bat` to get the correct environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime of searching and failing I had to generate it by VS13 vsvars32.bat note that vsvars not VS17's vcvars that generated 32-bit dll and because my platform is 64-bit I had to install and switch to 32-bit JVM and problem is resolved.

Comment: I could do it with VS15 too.