# How to fix jni.h throwing “stdio.h no file found error”

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, java-native-interface

NOTE: This is my second question asked with the same title. THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS NOT A DUPLICATE, PLEASE READ THE WHOLE THING.

I've been researching this for the past couple days now. and I honestly can't figure out whats wrong. I'm trying to get JNI to work with my application, but this is my first time I've used it and I don't know exactly what I'm doing and I keep running into problems. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, but I also have visual studio 2015 installed. This is hopefully my final problem but I don't know how to fix it. I ran this command:

```
cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\
jdk1.8.0_181\include\win32" -LD CPPWrapper.cpp -FeCPPWrapper.dll
```

and the error for that command is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\include\jni.h(39): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

I kinda understand whats wrong from this thread: [JNI: vcvars32.bat gives me "Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651123/jni-vcvars32-bat-gives-me-cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h-no-such-file-or)

but I don't exactly understand how I'm supposed to fix it, thanks for the help!

Note: I'm not very great with the command line, so you may have to explain it a little simpler for me, thanks!

I ran into a problem earlier with jni.h not being found, but was able to fix that, now I've been on this problem for 2+ hours and can't figure out exactly what I'm supposed to do to fix this.

Comment: Can you attach the relevant parts of CPPWrapper.cpp?